# MKPinAnnotationView not display properly

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

The annotationView bubble size is too small 9 out of 10 times. 
I call `[self.mapView selectAnnotation:self.selectedVenue animated:YES];` to show annotation view when select a row. Whether I set `animated:` `YES` or `NO` it still displays wrong size. However, if I increase size of map view height to at lease 200 pixels, everything looks fine except for the map view is too big for 3.5" screen.

I want the map view to be this size and annotation bubble to cover the title and subtitle correctly.

image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5105730/anno.png

Here's how I create my annotation view.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[FSVenue class]]) {
    static NSString *PlaceAnnotationIdentifier = @"Place Identifier";

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:PlaceAnnotationIdentifier];

    if (annotationView == nil)  {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:PlaceAnnotationIdentifier];
    }

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    UIButton *calloutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:(UIButtonTypeContactAdd)];
    calloutButton.tintColor = self.themeColor;

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton;
    annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;

    return annotationView;
}

return nil;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to zoom the visible rect of your mapview after adding your annotations like this.

```
[self.yourMapview addAnnotations:self.yourAnnotationsArray];
[self zoomToAnnotations];
```

Call this method after adding your annotation like this

```
-(void)zoomToAnnotations{

    MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;

    for (_yourAnnotation in self.yourMapView.annotations) {
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(_yourAnnotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
            zoomRect = pointRect;
        }else{
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
    }
    if (zoomRect.size.width == 0.10) /* for single annotation available in map */
    {
        zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(zoomRect.origin.x, zoomRect.origin.y, 100000, 100000);
    }

    [[self yourMapView] setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50) animated:YES];

}
```